# how to automatically indent a python code why instrumenting a code ..?

Tags: python, indentation, auto-indent

I am reverse engineering a python application. Through which i will be observing the behavior by dynamically instrumenting code inside the application. The problem is i need to insert the code at the correct level of indentation.

For example lets consider a fragment of code i will be instrumenting:

```
class A:
     def move(self,name):
         name=self.name
         print name
     def move1(self):
         print 'dude'
```

Now for the above sample code i will be instrumenting entry and exit logging and the instrumented code should look like this below

```
enter code class A:
     def move(self,name):
         print 'Entry move class='A''
         name=self.name
         print name
         Print'Exit move class='A''
     def move1(self):
         print 'Entry move1 class='A''
         print 'dude'
         print 'Exit move class='A''
```

This what i need when instrument the code instead i get the following:

```
enter code class A:
     def move(self,name):
print 'Entry move class='A''
             name=self.name
             print name
print'Exit move class='A''
         def move1(self):
print 'Entry move1 class='A''
             print 'dude'
print'Exit move1 class='A''
```

Because i am writing a script it insert into the next line and doesnt know the indentation format for a python code.

Is there anyway i could automatically adjust the indentation while inserting or i should need to know the index of the character in the next line and insert spaces to the string and then insert.

Comment: Look at the `:` colon; it indicates an indentation level is expected to increase..

Comment: Other than that, you probably want to start with the [`ast` parse tree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) to get a *much better* feel for the meaning of the code. Or switch to using [decorators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators) on your classes and functions instead of inserting print statements everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, it's actually fairly easy:

- The "entry" message should have exactly the same indentation as the statement that follows it.
- The "exit" message should have exactly the same indentation as the corresponding "entry" message.

That said, you can simplify the job considerably by using a decorator instead of the two explicit `print` statements. Something like `@trace` from [this page](http://www.itmaybeahack.com/book/python-2.6/html/p03/p03c06_decorators.html#defining-decorators) is much easier to insert into the  code than pairs of `prints`.

To take things even further, instead of modifying the source files, you could perform the instrumentation on the fly.